# How do I ask a good question on Stack Exchange site 'Programmers'?

Tags: support, asking-questions

Recently, I posted questions on the [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/about) Stack Exchange site. But every question whichever I asked was closed. Why? How do I frame questions and post?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation

Comment: You should read the FAQ section about, how to Ask a Question.

Comment: Even this question has careless grammar and spelling.  Please write proper English.

Comment: On SO you can ask **specific** questions about a programming task where you are currently stuck and not asking for help like: I want to develop something. How can I do it.

Comment: The 2 non-deleted questions I see on your account at Programmers were both closed as Off Topic; the first has a comment from a diamond moderator explaining that Programmers is for conceptual questions, not questions about implementation. The one that was migrated to SO and then closed as Not a Real Question was most likely because you included a giant traceback without showing the code that produced it, which is impossible to debug.

Answer (score 8):

When you click on the Ask Question button there's a link in the sidebar to the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) page.  Please also refer to the articles linked in the sidebar on that page.

Answer (score 2):

It seems both of [your questions on the Programmers site](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/93523/user2358783) were closed as off topic. I am not very familiar with the Programmers site, but you might be better off asking your questions on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com).

Stack Overflow accepts some types of questions, while Programmer's accepts other types. There might even be questions that are appropriate for both. In my view, this can certainly be confusing for someone that is not familiar with the nuances of the Stack Exchange network.

For better detail as to what topics are accepted on what sites, take a look at the "on-topic" page for each site:

- [Stack Overflow's On-Topic Page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
- [Programmer's On-Topic Page](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)